# How to retrieve Youtube Video Length in android?

Tags: android, android-youtube-api, android-video-player

In my app i have youtube video url. Now how can i get the duration of video from that url?

I used this code but it doesn't work. Any other way to get the video duration?

```
MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        retriever.setDataSource("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + videoID);
        String time = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
        long timeInmillisec = Long.parseLong(time);
        long duration = timeInmillisec / 1000;
        long hours = duration / 3600;
        long minutes = (duration - hours * 3600) / 60;
        long seconds = duration - (hours * 3600 + minutes * 60);
        Toast.makeText(this, "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + videoID + "\n" + hours + " : " + minutes + " : " + seconds, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 2):

if you have a youtube player instantiated with this id you can get the video duration from him.

```
 @Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean wasRestored) {

    if (!wasRestored) {
        youTubePlayer.loadVideo(videoID);
        this.youtubePlayer=youTubePlayer;

    }

}
```

and then you can do

```
youtubePlayer.getDurationMillis()
```

to get total video's time. Note that it will return 0 when video is loading so you might need to watch the evolution of the value returned and wait for it.

regards,

Comment: how can i know when its loaded or are there any callback when video is loaded ?

Comment: ah i found solution for it . youtubeplayer has eventlistener method setPlayerStateChangeListener to handle it